# I was Trying Merge sort but Not getting proper output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was Trying Merge sort but Not getting proper output

getting output [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

value is not merging in my array b why ?
what's wrong in the code?

can anyone please help to Understand this?

```
def merge(a, low, high, mid):
        b = [0]*len(a)
        
    
        i = low
        j = mid+1
    
        k = low
        while (i <= mid and j <= high):
            if a[i] < a[j]:
                b[k] = a[i]
    
                i += 1
                k += 1
            else:
                b[k] = a[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1
        while(i <= mid):
            b[k] = a[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while(j <= high):
            b[k] = a[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            a[i] = b[i]
    
    
    
    
    def mergeSort(a, low, high):
    
        if (low < high):
            mid = (low+high)//2
            mergeSort(a, low, mid)
            mergeSort(a, mid+1, high)
            merge(a, low, high, mid)
    
    
    arr = [55, 3, 100, 32, 5, 1, 22]
    low = 0
    high = len(arr)-1
    mergeSort(arr, low, high)
    print(arr)
```

Comment: The first time through `merge` it's called with low = 0, mid = 0, and high = 1. This thus only places two values into `b` (positions 0 and 1). This is then copied back into `a`, giving `[3, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. That has immediately wiped 5 values from the array you're trying to sort. That continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `merge` copies in `a` all the values from `b`, but only a part of `b` has been populated, so the next iteration will find a few zeros in `a` and soon `a` will only contain zeros.
Just replace

```
        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            a[i] = b[i]
```

with

```
        for i in range(low, high+1):
            a[i] = b[i]
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I got it